# Toshiba laptop shuts down immediately

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply, power, toshiba-laptop

I have a problem with a laptop which I am trying to fix.

The computer is a **Toshiba Satellite L50-A-165**

[Laptop spec](http://www.toshiba.pt/discontinued-products/satellite-l50-a-165/)

The laptop was working fine until one morning when attempting to start it.

**Symptoms:**

When we press start, the normal lights, fan and disk start working but after 2 seconds they all shutdown. No screen feedback or sound.

**What I have tried with no impact:**

**From the outside:**

-Power reset

-I tried with a different power supply.

-Removed the battery, power reset and with different power supply

**Then I started opening the laptop:**

-Removed the hard drive.

-Removed the small battery and power reset.

-Check for any loose cables and connectors.

-Tried without RAM. Then cleaned it and the slots.

-Disconnected the keyboard, Wi-Fi and USB adaptors.

-Checked again for any loose cables and connectors.

-Disconnected the screen.

-Removed the heatsink.

-completely removed the motherboard from the laptop case, making it run directly from the power supply.

**could it still be a power problem or a motherboard fault?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For start, I would remove, as you did, all the drives (optical and hdds).

Has the laptop experienced any shock? I would suggest reseating the cpu and ram in their respective sockets and slots, just in case.

Double check the cpu fan connector and lcd (ribbon) cable. Make sure they are properly connected and not damaged....